# Transforming data frame into Series creates NA's

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I've downloaded dataframe and tried to create pd.Series from this DataFrame

```
data = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = "train.csv", index_col = 0)
data.columns

Index([u'qid1',u'qid2',u'question1',u'question2'], dtype = 'object')
```

Here is columns in DataFrame, `qid1` is ID of `question1` and `qid2` is ID for `question2`
Also, there is no `Nan` in my DataFrame:

```
data.question1.isnull().sum()
0
```

I want to create pandas.Series() from first questions with `qid1` as index:

```
question1 = pd.Series(data.question1, index = data.qid1)
question1.isnull.sum()
68416
```

And now, there are 68416 Null values in my Series. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

pass anonymous values so the `Series` ctor doesn't try to align:

```
question1 = pd.Series(data.question1.values, index = data.qid1)
```

The problem here is that `question1` column has it's own index so it's going to try to use this during the construction

Example:

```
In [12]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(5), 'b':list('abcde')})
df

Out[12]:
   a  b
0  0  a
1  1  b
2  2  c
3  3  d
4  4  e

In [13]:
s = pd.Series(df['a'], index = df['b'])
s

Out[13]:
b
a   NaN
b   NaN
c   NaN
d   NaN
e   NaN
Name: a, dtype: float64

In [14]:
s = pd.Series(df['a'].values, index = df['b'])
s

Out[14]:
b
a    0
b    1
c    2
d    3
e    4
dtype: int32
```

Effectively what happens here is that you're reindexing your existing column with the passed in new index, because there are no index values that match you get `NaN`